# Получения UUID Android device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я в приложении для индефикации пользователя использую uuid девайса. Недавно начал использовать такую систему. Так вот в настаящее время я использую такой код для получения uuid:

```
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return "Consider calling";
    }
    String id = manager.getDeviceId();
```

но потом замечаю на сервере что часто приходит Дефолтный uuid (а значит что getDeviceId() возращает null). Есть ли какой то способ получения сто процентов uuid?

Comment: Логин/пароль - 100%, другие способы отрезает Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что разрешение ***READ_PHONE_STATE*** входит в список [Dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview), поэтому если пользователь не предоставил разрешение на доступ, то вы ничего и не получите

Советую прочитать следующие статьи и выбрать наиболее подходящую реализацию получения/генерации уникального идентификатора исходя из ваших задач:

- [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids)
- [Identifying App Installations](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)
- [How to retrieve an Unique ID to identify Android devices](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/how-to-retrieve-an-unique-id-to-identify-android-devices-6f99fd5369eb)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ выше достаточно полный, но все-таки приведу код моего варианта решения: `String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`
Потребуется импорт java.util.UUID;